# i have append the table in html from javascript but now i want to call a onclick function from font awesome icons by passing their id

Tags: javascript

I am calling an onclick function but it is not working

```
    for(var i =0; i<data.data.length; i++)    {
            console.log(data.data[i]._id); 
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tr.innerHTML = '<td>'+j+'</td><td>'+data.data[i].name+'</td>
            <td>'+data.data[i].email+'</td><td>'+data.data[i].gender+'</td>
            <td>'+data.data[i].gender+'</td><td>'+data.data[i].address+'</td>
            <td>'+data.data[i].city+'</td><td>'+data.data[i].state+'</td>
            <td>'+data.data[i].pin+'</td><td>'+data.data[i].country+'</td><td>
            <span><i class = "fa fa-pencil" onclick="edit('+data.data[i]._id+')">
            </i>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></td></tr>';
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
            j++;
      }
```

Comment: You need to escape the id parameter unless they are coincidentally all numeric.

Comment: Provide data and HTML

Comment: Refer to: [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the solutions.

Instead of passing the ID, it uses `.parentElement` property to get to the whole row that the icon is attached to.

In your template, inside `<i>` tag, I added `onclick="myFunction(event)"` which will execute `myFunction(e)` on every icon.

---

```js
let data = {
  data: [{
      name: "Holmes",
      email: "someemail@mail.com",
      gender: "male",
      address: "221B Baker Street",
      city: "London",
      state: "London",
      pin: "x",
      country: "England",
      _id: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Barry",
      email: "someemail@mail.com",
      gender: "male",
      address: "221B Baker Street",
      city: "London",
      state: "London",
      pin: "x",
      country: "England",
      _id: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Holmes",
      email: "someemail@mail.com",
      gender: "male",
      address: "221B Baker Street",
      city: "London",
      state: "London",
      pin: "x",
      country: "England",
      _id: 3
    }
  ]
}

let j = 0;
let tbody = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody');

for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
  //console.log(data.data[i]._id);
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + j + '<td>' + data.data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data.data[i].email + '</td><td>' + data.data[i].gender + '</td><td>' + data.data[i].gender + '</td><td>' + data.data[i].address + '</td><td>' + data.data[i].city + '</td><td>' + data.data[i].state + '</td><td>' + data.data[i].pin + '</td><td>' + data.data[i].country + '</td><td><span><i class = "fa fa-pencil" onclick="edit(' + data.data[i]._id + ')"></i>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-trash" onclick="myFunction(event)"></i></span></td></tr>';
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
  j++;
}

function myFunction(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  let targetSpan = target.parentElement;
  let targetTd = targetSpan.parentElement;
  let targetTr = targetTd.parentElement;
  targetTr.style.background = "yellow";
  //console.log(targetTr);
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table id="myTable">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you it works. I just added some jquery in myfunction and it works fine.

Comment: Cool. Happy to help! :) @MayankGupta